# Asking user to select file path results in run time error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

this worked for me when I had specified the pdf file path directly.  Now that i ask for the user to select the file path it gives a run time error 6269. the error comes on the SaveAs2 line.

```
Sub PDFToWord1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Dim wa As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

wa.Visible = False

Dim pdfPath As String

MsgBox ("Select the pdf you wish to add")

pdfPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set doc = wa.Documents.Open(pdfPath)

MsgBox Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx")

doc.SaveAs2 Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx")

MsgBox ("got here")

doc.Close True

wa.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the *text* of the error message?  If you use `wa.Visible = True` while debugging you might get some idea of what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try explicitly stating the file format when you save the document. For instance, you can use the following code to save the document as a Word Document (*.docx):

```
doc.SaveAs2 Filename:=Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx"), 
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

Try this:

```
Sub PDFToWord1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Dim wa As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

wa.Visible = False

Dim pdfPath As String

MsgBox ("Select the pdf you wish to add")

pdfPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set doc = wa.Documents.Open(pdfPath)

MsgBox Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx")

doc.SaveAs2 Filename:=Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx"), 
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

MsgBox ("got here")

doc.Close True

wa.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: This might be an obvious question but why did explicitly stating the format fix the issue I was having?  And side question why that not come up when I had just hard coded the path?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub PDFToWord1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = True

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim pdfPath As String
    
    wordApp.Visible = False
    
    MsgBox ("Select the pdf you wish to add")

    pdfPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(pdfPath)

    wordDoc.SaveAs2 Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx")

    wordDoc.Close True

    wordApp.Quit
        
    MsgBox Replace(pdfPath, ".pdf", ".docx")

End Sub
```